# Conta de serviços google API, nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-api

Ola estou com o código a seguir para gerar um token de requisição, pra a API do google classroom.

Porem, mesmo colocando uma conta como subject, ele retorna os dados de outra conta existente que não coloquei no parâmetro.

A conta de serviço esta com permissão em todo domínio para os escopos a baixo e demais necessários, porem mesmo passando 'email.donosala@serv.br' (apenas um exemplo), ele retorna dados de outra conta exemplo:email.donosala05@serv.br

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis'); 
const axios = require("axios")

  var configuration = {
        'pedagogico_account': 'email.donosala@serv.br',
        'SCOPE':[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly"]  
      };
    const Pedagogico_key = require('../../conf/nova_chave_all_scopes.json');

    const PainelPedagogico = new google.auth.JWT(
      Pedagogico_key.client_email,
      null,
      Pedagogico_key.private_key,
      configuration.SCOPE,
      configuration.pedagogico_account
    
    );
    PainelPedagogico.authorize(async (err, tokens) =>  ( err ? console.log('PainelPedagogico:',err) : ( () => {console.log("Google-API PainelPedagogico Authed!");})()));
      



// chamada 

  let acesso = PainelPedagogico.credentials.access_token
      const auth = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + acesso
        }
      };

      axios.get('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/515923210164/topics',auth
      ) .then(response => {
        console.log('Response',response)
     })
     .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error ', e)
     });
```

alguma ideia do que pode ser ?

Comment: Tu consegues mandar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível, com dados exemplo para que a comunidade possa analisar com mais detalhes?

Comment: vou ajustar, assim que possivel atualizo o código.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atualizando a resposta, descobri que devido as minhas contas que são donas das salas, serem admin, mesmo passando uma conta especifica ela lista todas as turmas, com contas padrões o problema não persiste.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).